# angular library - how to prevent published npm package to export minified component and module names

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-library, ng-packagr

I've followed this [guide here](https://tomastrajan.medium.com/the-best-way-to-architect-your-angular-libraries-87959301d3d3) to create an angular library, which I've successfully published to our gitlab package registry.

I was able to install the package without any problems, but I wasn't able to import my library modules. In the node_modules I was able to see that all the module names were sort of minified.

```
/**
 * Generated bundle index. Do not edit.
 */
export * from './index';
export { ScrapTypeTimeSeriesChartComponent as ɵf } from './lib/components/scrap-type-time-series-chart/scrap-type-time-series-chart.component';
export { ScrapTypeTimeSeriesChartModule as ɵe } from './lib/components/scrap-type-time-series-chart/scrap-type-time-series-chart.module';
export { ScrapTypeTimeSeriesChartService as ɵg } from './lib/components/scrap-type-time-series-chart/scrap-type-time-series-chart.service';
export { WorkplaceActiveStatusWidgetComponent as ɵb } from './lib/components/workplace-active-status-widget/workplace-active-status-widget.component';
export { WorkplaceActiveStatusWidgetModule as ɵa } from './lib/components/workplace-active-status-widget/workplace-active-status-widget.module';
export { DatePipe as ɵd } from './lib/shared/pipes/date.pipe';
export { TimerPipe as ɵc } from './lib/shared/pipes/timer.pipe';

//# sourceMappingURL=company-core-ui.d.ts.map
```

After a bit of research, I've found an [issue on the ng-packagr](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35255#issuecomment-669192452) where the last comment was asking the same, but the issue got closed. Does anyone else knows where the problem is and how I can configure my angular library project correctly?

I've using angular 12. Below are the configs of the library project.

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": ".",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "esnext",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@company/core-ui": ["dist/core-ui", "libs/core-ui/src/index"],
            "@company/core-ui/*": ["libs/core-ui", "libs/core-ui/*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

tsconfig.lib.json

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
        "target": "es2015",
        "declaration": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "types": [],
        "lib": ["dom", "es2018"]
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
        "strictMetadataEmit": true,
        "enableResourceInlining": true,
        "enableIvy": false
    },
    "exclude": ["src/test-setup.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.stories.ts", "**/*.stories.js"],
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to explicitly export the Tokens to avoid uglification.
So in the outer most barrel I have to

```
export { ScrapTypeTimeSeriesChartComponent } from './lib/components/scrap-type-time-series-chart/scrap-type-time-series-chart.component';
...
```